# undefined references in GCC6 to 'rt','pthread','stdc++fs'

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cmake

just faced with a GCC on ubuntu when was trying to build my sample project,
found those three libraries (from subject) required to link.
and also found that order of '-lxxx' parameters is important in a commandline

however I'm using cmake as a build system and could find this applying to cmake.

currently this is :

```
if (${GCC})
     target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} rt pthread stdc++fs)
endif (${GCC})
```

and it doesn't work for me, linker still can't find referred symbols from all referred libs.

could someone help with this libraries linkage from cmake perspective?

Comment: What happens if you remove the conditional?

Comment: what was wrong with a condition? because thanks a lot! it works. I've just added this statement, previously there were for MSVC and MINGW only.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the value of `${GCC}`?  Is it true?

Comment: @amigo421 I've posted an answer detailing this :)

Comment: Take a look at the [CMake standard variable documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-variables.7.html), especially the [list of variable describing the system](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-describe-the-system) which doesn't list a `GCC` variable. Instead you could use e.g. [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) to see if the compiler is GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, your conditions is always false (the variable doesn't exist AFAIK), so the statements inside of it are never taken into account!

You need to change:

```
if(${GCC})
```

To:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
```

Or:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
```

This now checks if the C++ compiler is gcc/g++.

Comment: Or use the built-in `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX `

Comment: thank you! I don't remember where I found ${GCC} , but thou that saw this  somewhere in cmake manual....

Comment: ${UNIX} is more useful in my case, to split the logic between VC, MINGW, and GCC (UNIX). the variable above covers GCC and MINGW which should have different logic